# why doesn't the loop run "definite" number of times?

Tags: php, memcached, while-loop

I've this code in php using memcache :

```
<?php

$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");

$version = $memcache->getVersion();
echo "Server's version: ".$version."<br/>\n";

$tmp_object = new stdClass;
$tmp_object->str_attr = 'test';
$tmp_object->int_attr = 123;

$memcache->set('key', $tmp_object, false, 1) or die ("Failed to save data at t\
he server");
echo "Store data in the cache (data will expire in 1 second)<br/>\n";
$i=0;
do{
  $get_result = $memcache->get('key');
  echo "Data from the cache:<br/>\n";
  var_dump($get_result);
  $i++;
}while($get_result);
echo $i;
var_dump($get_result);
```

the value of $i is different every time.. Sometimes it is 140, sometimes it is 900+, etc... Why does it change ?

edit -
btw, that is an example program for memcached from php website with minor alterations.

**edit**
I guess I wasn't clear enough with question :
I meant to ask, why does the `$memcache->get('key')` execution takes more cpu times in some cases while it takes less cpu time in other cases.
=> more loops means `$memcache->get('key')` happened to take less time, less loops means it took more cpu time.
Keep in mind that cache is set to expire within 1 second and `do - while` executes until it expires.

Comment: $i reflects the number of $memcache->get/'key') items you have. Has long as there are any, $i is incremented by 1. At the end of the loop, you print out how many times it looped

Comment: `while` loops (or `do ... while` loops) are not timing loops on PCs anymore. Haven't been for... at least a decade or so now.

Comment: @Damien Pirsy : @Ignacio : Question updated to reflect my thoughts more clearly :) Pls take a second look now ... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop keeps running and is reading the same key over and over again, until it is removed from memcache.

The expire time for that key is set to 1 second, so the number of times the loop runs is the number of times the value can be read in 1 second. The expire time is just an indication. It doen't necessarily have to be 1 second exact to the millisecond. And the speed of your script can depend on various other conditions as well, so this counter isn't very reliable.

Comment: Now that is a real answer... So you mean to say the memcached's timer isn't accurate or exact ?

Comment: That, and the execution time of the script can be influenced by other activities too. I don't know your configuration, but a server uses caching too, and if you got APC cache or got a database or cron jobs, those can influence the speed both positively and negatively. If you develop on a live server (even a separate environment on a live server), or you use the server with multiple users, this can affect the performance dramatically. Something as fast like a for loop can return a completely different result when it gets the chance to run half a second longer.

Comment: But to come back to memcache; I don't know all ins and outs of it, but it seems illogical that it uses a high resolution timer to clean up a piece of data exacly on the millisecond. You pass an expiration time in seconds. Memcache will run sort of an internal cron job to check which items are outdated and clean them up. This will run quite often, but not so often that you can build an accurate timer on it.

Comment: Thanks for the gyan :) helpful

Answer (score -2):

$i is printed out side the loop so as long as your do while loop condition get true..$i will get increment so you get different result.

Comment: @Shrinath : Thanks for the comment. But this site is, to get help and help others. A small correction can help. So every post should be appreciated. Since, an answer to any post means quality time of members.